# How to access Model from Views in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, view, model

How to access Model from Views in Codeigniter.

I have a Model with a function, i need to call this function from view

Comment: then what controller suppose to do?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: @always-a-learner he has now removed his account looks like

Comment: It's heart braking that he didn't stay till accept the answer. :)) @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 1):

Please Read the CI documentation First:

If You are using a `MVC` Structured Framework then you should be following the way it works.

You Need the Controller:

```
public function your_controller_function(){

    // To load model
    $this->load->model ('your_model');

    //To Call model function form controller
    $data = $this->your_model->model_function($ex_data);

    //TO Send data to view
    $this->load->view('your_view',['data'=>$data]);
}
```

Inside your model:

```
public function model_function($ex_data){
    // Your Querys
    // user return to send you query result to the controller anything
   // Sample Example of query and return

    $query = $this->db->select('*')     
    ->where('your_column',$data['column_name'])
    ->get('your_table');

    $your_result = $query->row_array();

    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
         return your_result;

     } else {

        return FALSE;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your view you can write :

```
<?php
$this->load->model('your_model');
$this->your_model->some_function();
?>
```

Comment: You can't call `$this->load->model('your_model');` in a *View*, you can call it only within a *Controller*.

Answer (score -2):

For example in `User_controller` load User Model `$this->load->model('Users_model');`

Then User View page `$viewpage = this->Users_model->somefunction($id);`

Comment: Your Suggested answer is not a good practice for `MVC` structured framwork.